# How to remove applied coupon code in a custom controller on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, discount, coupon-codes

I have a custom controller where i apply coupon code discount like this:

```
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode($discount)
                            ->collectTotals()
                            ->save();
```

Now, like magento 2 default does, I want to be able to remove that coupon code discount.

So i created a custom controller and i want to remove here the discount:

the only thing i found to remove the coupon discount is this:

```
$couponCode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1
        ? ''
        : trim($this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code'));
```

But this dosen't work for me.

Does anyone know what it's the right way to remove this discounts in my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `setCouponCode('')` with empty value.

```
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode('')
                            ->collectTotals()
                            ->save();
```

Comment: so this will remove my applied coupon code?

Comment: Yes, this will remove your coupon code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    public function __construct( 
         \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
         \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     ) { 
         $this->cart = $cart;
         $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
     }
     public function functionName(){
      $cartQuote = $this->cart->getQuote();
      $oldCouponCode = $cartQuote->getCouponCode();
      $codeLength = strlen($oldCouponCode);
       if($codeLength){     
         $cartQuote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
         $cartQuote->setCouponCode('')->collectTotals();//Removing coupon 
         $this->quoteRepository->save($cartQuote);
    }  
}
```